# Adding app icon to android listview beside text

Tags: android, listview, icons

i wanted to know how i can add icons beside the application name which is called in androids listview. Yes, i searched and tried various methods to my knowledge but remained unsuccessful, any help is appreciated :)

```
package mobi.omegacentauri.appcontrol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import mobi.omegacentauri.appcontrol.R;
import mobi.omegacentauri.appcontrol.appcontrolService.IncomingHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.NumberKeyListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class appcontrol extends Activity implements ServiceConnection {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    static final String MARKET = "Market";

    public static final DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("0.0");   

    private ToggleButton activeBox;
    private boolean active;

    private Messenger messenger = null;

    private SharedPreferences options;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private boolean getOut = false;
    public ListView appsList;

    static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public static Setting[] getSettings(Context context, SharedPreferences pref) {
        Setting[] allSettings = new Setting[]{ 
                new FontSize(context, pref),
                new OrientationSetting(context, pref),
                new TimeoutSetting(context, pref),
                new BoostSetting(context, pref),
                new MinCPUSetting(context, pref),
                new MaxCPUSetting(context, pref)
        };

        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<allSettings.length; i++)
            if (allSettings[i].isActive())
                count++;

        Setting[] settings = new Setting[count];

        count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<allSettings.length; i++) {
            if (allSettings[i].isActive())
                settings[count++] = allSettings[i];
        }

        log(""+count+" settings active");

        return settings;
    }

    public static void log(String s) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.v("appcontrol", s);
    }

    private void message(String title, String msg) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(msg));
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, 
                getResources().getText(R.string.ok), 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {} });
        alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {} });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void firstTime() {
        if (! options.getBoolean(Options.PREF_FIRST_TIME, true))
            return;

        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = options.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(Options.PREF_FIRST_TIME, false);
        ed.commit();           

        String msg;
        msg = "With appcontrol, you can have some different settings in different applications";
        message("Welcome", msg);
    }

    public void helpButton(View v) {
        help();
    }

    private void saveOS() {
    }

    private void restoreOS() {
    }

    void stopService() {
        log("stop service");
        stopService(new Intent(this, appcontrolService.class));
        restoreOS();
    }

    void saveSettings() {
    }

    void bind() {
        log("bind");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, appcontrolService.class);
        bindService(i, this, 0);
    }

    void restartService(boolean bind) {
        stopService();
        saveSettings();     
        Intent i = new Intent(this, appcontrolService.class);
        log("restartService:starting service");
        startService(i);
        if (bind) {
            bind();
        }
    }

    void setActive(boolean value, boolean bind) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = options.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(Options.PREF_ACTIVE, value);
        ed.commit();
        if (value) {
            log("setActive:restartService");
            restartService(bind);
        }
        else {
            stopService();
        }
        active = value;
        updateNotification();
    }

    public void PleaseBuy(String title, String text, final boolean exit) {      
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);        
        alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text));

        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, 
                "Go to "+MARKET, 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                market();
                if (exit) {
                    stopService();
                    finish();
                }
            } });
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, 
                "Not now", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (exit) {
                    stopService();
                    finish();
                }

            } });
        alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                if (exit)
                    finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();             
    }

    private void market() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (MARKET.contains("Appstore")) {
          // string split up to fool switcher.sh
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=mobi.omegacentauri.Screen" +"Dim."+"Full"));
        }
        else if (MARKET.contains("AndroidPIT")) {
            // string split up to fool switcher.sh
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/mobi.omegacentauri.Screen" +"Dim."+"Full"));
        }
        else {
          // string split up to fool switcher.sh
            i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.Screen" +"Dim."+"Full"));
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void changeLog() {
        message("Changes", getAssetFile("changelog.html"));
    }

    private void help() {
        message("Questions and Answers", getAssetFile(isKindle()?"kindlehelp.html":"help.html"));
    }

    private void versionUpdate() {
        int versionCode;
        try {
            versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            versionCode = 0;
        } 
        if (options.getInt(Options.PREF_LAST_VERSION, 0) != versionCode) {
            options.edit().putInt(Options.PREF_LAST_VERSION, versionCode).commit();
            changeLog();
        }

    }

    private void chooseSetting(final String app) {
        final Setting[] settings = getSettings(this, options);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final AlertDialog dialog; 
//      builder.setTitle("Choose setting");

        View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.choose_setting, null);

        ListView list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.settings);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Setting>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                settings) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v;             

                if (convertView == null) {
                    v = View.inflate(appcontrol.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
                }
                else {
                    v = convertView;
                }

                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1))
                    .setText(settings[position].getName());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2))
                    .setText(settings[position].describe(app));
                return v;
            }

        });

        builder.setView(v);

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

                log("chose "+settings[position].name);
                settings[position].dialog(appcontrol.this, app);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }           
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        log("onCreate");
        options = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        versionUpdate();
        firstTime();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        active = options.getBoolean(Options.PREF_ACTIVE, false);

//      if (active) {
//          restartService(true);
//      }
//      else {
//          stopService();
//      }

        activeBox = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.active);
        activeBox.setChecked(active);
        activeBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean value) {
                if (value && !active) {
                    saveOS();
                }
                setActive(value, true);

                if (value) {
                    message("Important information",
                            "If you wish to uninstall or upgrade appcontrol, uncheck the 'Active' "+
                            "button before uninstalling or upgrading, or some system resources "+
                            "will be wasted (they can be reclaimed by rebooting your device).");
                }
            }});

        appsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apps);

        appsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                MyApplicationInfo info = (MyApplicationInfo) appsList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                chooseSetting(info.packageName);                
            }           
        });

    }

    public void setNotification(Context c, NotificationManager nm, boolean active) {
        int icon = active?R.drawable.brightnesson:R.drawable.brightnessoff;

        if (Options.getNotify(options) == Options.NOTIFY_NEVER)
            icon = 0;

        Notification n = new Notification(
                icon,
                "appcontrol", 
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent i = new Intent(c, appcontrol.class);     
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 
        n.setLatestEventInfo(c, "appcontrol", "appcontrol is "+(active?"on":"off"), 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, i, 0));
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
        log("notify "+n.toString());
    }

    private void updateNotification() {
        updateNotification(this, options, notificationManager, active);
    }

    public void updateNotification(Context c, 
            SharedPreferences options, NotificationManager nm, boolean active) {
        log("notify "+Options.getNotify(options));
        switch(Options.getNotify(options)) {
        case Options.NOTIFY_AUTO:
            if (active)
                setNotification(c, nm, active);
            else {
                log("trying to cancel notification");
                nm.cancelAll();
            }
            break;
        case Options.NOTIFY_NEVER:
        case Options.NOTIFY_ALWAYS:
            setNotification(c, nm, active);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateNotification();

        if (getOut) { 
            log("getting out");
            return;
        }

        (new GetApps(this, appsList, getSettings(this, options))).execute();

        if (active) {
            restartService(true);
        }
        else {
            stopService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (getOut)
            return;

        saveSettings();

        if (messenger != null) {
            log("unbind");
            unbindService(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        log("onStop");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        log("onDestroy");
    }

    private boolean largeScreen() {
        int layout = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
        return (layout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;      
    }

    private boolean isKindle() {
        return Build.MODEL.equalsIgnoreCase("Kindle Fire");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU == keyCode) {
            onWhatToControl(null);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onWhatToControl(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Options.class));
    }

    public void onOptions(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Options2.class));
    }

    public void onOtherApps(View v) {
        MarketDetector.launch(this);
    }

    public void sendMessage(int n, int arg1, int arg2) {
        if (messenger == null) 
            return;

        try {
            log("message "+n+" "+arg1+" "+arg2);
            messenger.send(Message.obtain(null, n, arg1, arg2));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName classname, IBinder service) {
        log("connected");
        messenger = new Messenger(service);
        try {
            messenger.send(Message.obtain(null, IncomingHandler.MSG_RELOAD_SETTINGS, 0, 0));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        log("disconnected"); 
//      stopService(new Intent(this, appcontrolService.class));
        messenger = null;       
    }

    static private String getStreamFile(InputStream stream) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            String text = "";
            String line;
            while (null != (line=reader.readLine()))
                text = text + line;
            return text;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String getAssetFile(String assetName) {
        try {
            return getStreamFile(getAssets().open(assetName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: can you  post a screen shot of how it should look?

Comment: "remained unsuccessful" is a useless description. Please explain **completely and precisely** where you are having problems.

Comment: here is the screenshot: [link(http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wi3604&s=5)
and sorry for the description, what i meant was that, it didnt show up, the icon.

Comment: @user2558344 you want the icon in each row of listview next to the text?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, each apps icon to be next to the name or text.

Comment: @user2558344 follow commonsware's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon did not show up because your `ListView` row does not contain an `ImageView` or anything else that would represent an icon.

So, design your own row layout that contains an `ImageView` or something. Use that row layout to replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` when creating your `ArrayAdapter`. Then, in `getView()`, populate that `ImageView`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/Dynamic) demonstrating putting an icon in `ListView` rows. The row contains an `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ok"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the `ArrayAdapter` uses that row:

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    IconicAdapter() {
      super(DynamicDemo.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
      View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      if (items[position].length()>4) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
      }

      TextView size=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.size);

      size.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.size_template), items[position].length()));

      return(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: could he not use a compound textview? just my thought

Comment: @Raghunandan: I have no idea. His existing layout contains two `TextView` widgets. I have no idea what the OP expects this icon to look like, with respect to the other widgets. It is technically possible to use a compound drawable with a `TextView`, but whether or not that's the desired look and feel, I cannot say.

Comment: agreed.i failed to notice that op had two textview widgets.

Comment: her. sorry but, I'm pretty new to java, so I cant say that I understand how to implement this. But from what I understood, this won't be fetching the applications icon to display i.e,           
[ICON] App name.

Comment: @user2558344: I am showing you an example, from [a book](http://commonsware.com/Android), of how to put icons into `ListView` rows. Where *you* decide to get your icons from is *your* job, as that is for *your* app.

Comment: @CommonsWare implemented it. one last question, in what way do I get it to pull icons from seperate apps automatically? (in list)

Comment: @user2558344: I do not know what you mean by "automatically". You usually get the icon by calling `loadIcon()` on a `ResolveInfo` or something like that. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot